# Unknown GCC pragmas on Mac

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

```
warning: unknown pragma ignored [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma GCC optimize("O3")
```

I want to enable GCC optimization flags, but they are ignored when i'm compiling code, although they are present in [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html). Why does this happen?

Comment: On the Mac, `gcc` is sometimes an alias for `clang`, rather than the actual GCC. What do you get when you run `gcc --version`?

Comment: Oh, no.  It is clang. But the same warning occurs even if i use `-std=c++17` or `-std=gnu++17`

Comment: Beside the fact that `gcc` is likely `clang` on Mac, why do you set optimization level in the code? This is usually counterproductive. Why don't set optimization level as part of your build system?

Comment: It's all for competitive programming

Comment: You should not enable optimizations inside your code even for competitive programming. Build system takes care of that.

Comment: I liked when OP thought setting the C++ standard would help clang use gcc intrinsics.

Comment: `Oh, no. It is clang` Please post the exact version output of the compiler that you use, be it `gcc --version` or `clang --version`.

Comment: On macos `gcc --version` outputs `AppleClang`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apple LLVM 5.0 pragma optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768895/apple-llvm-5-0-pragma-optimize)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that g++ is a clang alias in MacOS by default
So i did this

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s g++-11 g++
```

this fixes the problem and g++ command will run actual gcc compuler instead of clang